# "Save" method Windows Powershell (windows 7) returns error

Tags: powershell, windows-7-x64, shortcut

I am trying to learn how to create a desktop shortcut using Windows powershell so that I can add a script with several shortcuts to the deployment of computers at my company.  Everything works well until I get to the $Shortcut.Save() command.

```bsh
    PS C:\Windows\system32> $TargetApp = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe"
    PS C:\Windows\system32> $WshShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
    PS C:\Windows\system32> $Shortcut + $WshShell.CreateShortcut("$Home\Desktop\Firefox.lnk")
    PS C:\Windows\system32> $Shortcut.TargetPath = $TargetApp
    PS C:\Windows\system32> $Shortcut.Save()
```

I am using firefox as a test.  When I run the last line, I get error:

```bsh
"Exception calling "Save" with "0" arguments(s): "Unable to save shortcut "C:\Desktop\Firefox.lnk".""
```

The code seems to work for other people, so could it be a setting on my computer?

Comment: I'm betting `C:\Desktop` doesn't exist. Does it work if you hard code a full path for `CreateShortcut`?

Comment: Thanks, that was the main problem.  For some reason I was thinking that directory was a valid shortcut.

Comment: If that was it then there is something wrong with your `$Home` variable. Check it to make sure it has the folder path you're expecting.

Comment: Also replace the `+` with `=` in `$Shortcut + $WshShell.CreateShortcut`